# Stacks, queues and linked lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue

I have started learning **Data Structures** recently, and just had my own `linked list` implementation.

Now I stumbled upon two new data structures: `stack`  and `queue`.
From what I have learned so far
`stack` is a `linked list` that allows insertion / removal only from its tail, and
 `queue` is a `linked list` that allows insertion only at its tail and removal only from its head.

My questions are:
Why would I use these two data structures instead of a regular `linked list` that allows insertion and removal from anywhere?
Also, Why are these two data structure classified as independent data structures rather than "limited access linked lists"?

Comment: stack and queue are basic DS abstraction. they are not necessary to be implemented using linked list. stack and queue represent two properties we want in our daily life, FILO and FIFO, respectively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Stacks and queues have their own reason of existence.
A stack is a FILO (First In Last Out) or LIFO (either ways) data structure that could be implemented using arrays, linked lists or other forms. Consider browser history. You navigate to *Site A* -> then *B* -> then *C* -> *D*. As a user moves ahead, you first **push** (insert at tail) the list of websites. This ensures that the current site is always at the top of the stack.
[image: Stack in action]

Then when the user hits back button, you **pop** the one at the top (removing from tail - the same end used for insertion) which gives the last visited site - *C*. Thus the concept of First In (which was *Site A*) and Last Out (the last one to go in was *Site D* which in turn became the first one to go out)

Similar could be said for queue which is FIFO (First In First Out). Consider the example of job queue. When performing a job, you would (not considering any optimization algorithms) serve the one first to arrive. This makes queue an excellent data structure to process jobs on a first come first serve basis.

In both the cases, you wouldn't want an arbitrary removal or insertion of elements at any index. No, that would result in an undesirable behaviour. Hence, the need for stack/queue. I would again emphasize that stacks/queues can be implemented by enforcing restrictions on linked lists.

Sorry for the poor image quality - I just drew it in paint.

Comment: Good example. I have a question.
*A stack is a FILO (First In Last Out) or LIFO (either ways) data structure that could be implemented using arrays*

if queue implemented with array. push complexity would be higher then link list.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla Based on the implementation for queues and stacks alike, the push times are similar. It's the removal of an item (from the start vs the end) that takes different times. Some languages (like JavaScript) have a method built in to remove items from stack (`pop`) and queue(`shift`). Created a fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/chechs/b9Lfu2do/15/ which shows huge time difference in Chrome & Opera for the two operations; Firefox and Safari still take higher time for shift, but not as much. You may experiment with `push` vs `pop` to check push complexity.

Answer (score 3):

> Stack is basically a data structure that follows LIFO (LAST IN FIRST
>   OUT). Queue is one which follows FIFO (FIRST IN FIRST OUT).

In general, `Stacks` and `Queues` can be implemented using `Arrays` and `Linked Lists`.

The reason you would use `Linked List` for implementing `Stack` is when you need a functionality involving LAST IN FIRST OUT form and you are not sure how many elements that functionality requires. So you would use `LinkedList` creating nodes dynamically depending on the requirement.

Same goes for `Queues`

The reason both are independent is because both follow different principles i.e LIFO and FIFO respectively.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a data structure with a certain relationship between elements in memory,
whereas the stack and queue are  data structures with a certain interface and behavior.Stack and queue can be implemented even in arrays, so they are data structures that follow a certain rule i.e. LIFO for stack and FIFO for queue,(they are not just limited to linked lists they can also implemented in other data structures like arrays what important is the behaviour and rule they follow)